# keyEquivalent with non-alpha numeric character in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In a context menu, I'd like `⌘→` to be a key equivalent.

In this [support document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonKeyEquiv.html), you can set it like so:

```
unichar arrowKey = NSLeftArrowFunctionKey;
[button setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&arrowKey length:1]];
```

However, I'm struggling to convert this to Swift.

How can you set permitted non-alpha numeric keys as the key equivalent in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code takes `NSLeftArrowFunctionKey` (a C macro), assigns it to a `unichar` variable, and then takes the address of it to give to `NSString`. Annoyingly, because it's a C macro and not a `const`, you can't just directly use `&NSLeftArrowFunctionKey`.

In Swift, `NSLeftArrowFunctionKey` is imported as `UInt16`, which can be used to create a `UnicodeScalar`, which can be used to create a `Character`, and ultimately a `String`.

Use this in Swift 2:

```
button.keyEquivalent = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(NSLeftArrowFunctionKey)))
```

Use this in Swift 3:

```
button.keyEquivalent = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(NSLeftArrowFunctionKey)!))
```

Comment: Ah. Simple. Is `String(NSRightArrowFunctionKey)` clearer?

Comment: @glenstorey I was mistaken in my first post. See my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect - just take the ! off - as you can't force unwrap a UnicodeScalar. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Oops, I was testing this in Swift 3, in which `UnicodeScalar(_:)` is failable.